# Split and rejoin part of a string in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm querying the github sample_files dataset in bigquery and I want to get the the path excluding the filename.

So if I have /path/to/file.txt
I want it to return /path/to

In python I could do something like

```
"/".join(str.split(a, "/")[0:-1])
```

but I'm not sure how to do that in bigquery/sql
Any ideas? THanks!

Answer (score 0):

One method is `regexp_replace()`:

```
regexp_replace('/path/to/file.txt', '/[^/]+$', '')
```

Comment: probably using REGEXP_EXTRACT() would be more straight forward

Comment: @JulioGB . . . I think `regexp_replace()` is simpler, which is why I suggest it.  Just remove the last item from the path.

Answer (score 0):

I would use REGEXP_EXTRACT as in below example

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(full_path, r'(.+)/[^/]*$')
```

> Split and rejoin part of a string in BigQuery

If for some reason you need or more comfortable with mimicking same approach (Split and rejoin) with SPLIT as in your question  - you can use below approach (provided along with sample data for testing , playing with)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '/path/to/file.txt' full_path UNION ALL
  SELECT '/path/to/'
)
SELECT full_path, 
  (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(part, '/') 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(full_path, '/')) part WITH OFFSET
    WHERE OFFSET < ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(full_path, '/')) - 1
  ) path
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row full_path           path     
1   /path/to/file.txt   /path/to     
2   /path/to/           /path/to
```